# django multiple form separated in the html, merge again with submit

Tags: html, django, django-forms

there is a formmodel like:

```
class foo(forms.ModelForm):
        a = forms.BooleanField(label='a', required=False)
        b = forms.BooleanField(label='b', required=False)
        c = forms.BooleanField(label='c', required=False)
        d = forms.BooleanField(label='d', required=False)
        e = forms.BooleanField(label='e', required=False)
        f = forms.BooleanField(label='f', required=False)
        g = forms.BooleanField(label='g', required=False)
        h = forms.BooleanField(label='h', required=False)
        #...
```

further there are multiple instances of foo in a list:

```
L = []
L.append(foo(instance=object_1))
L.append(foo(instance=object_2))
L.append(foo(instance=object_3))
#...
L.append(foo(instance=object_n))
```

this is shown on the html in different tables in different columns.
The problem now is to send the data back correctly with subbmit. I have to put the tables and lines back together correctly. I was thinking of something like this:

```
<form class="form-inline" action ="{% url 'bla:blo' %}" method="post">
      Table #1
               | ID of Form | Value #1 | Value #2 | Value #3 | Value #4 |
               | ---------- | -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- |
    <form id=1>|     1      |    a1    |    b1    |    c1    |    d1    |</form>
    <form id=2>|     2      |    a2    |    b2    |    c2    |    d2    |</form>
    <form id=3>|     3      |    a3    |    b3    |    c3    |    d3    |</form>
    <form id=4>|     4      |    a4    |    b4    |    c4    |    d4    |</form>

      Table #2
               | ID of Form | Value #1 | Value #2 | Value #3 | Value #4 |
               | ---------- | -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- |
    <form id=1>|     1      |    e1    |    f1    |    g1    |    h1    |</form>
    <form id=2>|     2      |    e2    |    f2    |    g2    |    h2    |</form>
    <form id=3>|     3      |    e3    |    f3    |    g3    |    h3    |</form>
    <form id=4>|     4      |    e4    |    f4    |    g4    |    h4    |</form>

    {% csrf_token %}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark">Save</button>
</form>
```

i.e. the rows of the table with the same form id must be converted back into the same django form.

the submit must then of course still be accepted in the `view.py`
kinda like that

```
def boo(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            f = foo(request.POST):
            # f[0] = form id 1
            # f[1] = form id 2
            # f[2] = form id 3
            # ...
            # f[n] = form id n
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only send multiple forms via context, but getting all these form data using another wrapper form will not be possible. You can only see the list of forms, but you may not be able to get data using post requests for all forms.

```py
def boo(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
       form_list = []
       object_list = [] # YOUR_OBJECT_LIST
       for instance in object_list:
           form_list.append(foo(instance=instance))
       return render("footemplate.html", context={"forms": form_list})
    if request.method == "POST":
```

```html
<form>
  {% csrf_token %}
  {% for form in forms %}
     {{ form }}
  {% endfor %}
</form>
```

To send all forms data via post request, I will suggest using javascript and ajax. and for backend part, use RestfulAPI to handle this complex system